# How to cast an Object to GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, casting

I tried to get Terrains from `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(Terrain))`, and then activate it depend on the situations.

But it return `Objects`.

I had tried to cast it to GameObject by `(GameObect)obj` and `obj as GameObject`.

The first one raised an `Invalid cast` error, and the second returned a `null`.

The examples I was able to find online talked about `Resources.Load` mostly, which requires `Instantiation`.

But I don't think `FindObjectsOfTypeAll` requires instantiation, because the GameObjects are "already there"! Right!?

So could somebody please be so kind and teach me how can I cast Objects into GameObject so I could activated it!?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Terrain`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.html) is a [component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html), so its associated `GameObject` is accessed via the `gameObject` property.

Something like:

```
var go = ((Terrain)obj).gameObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi think you could use something like finding the terrain with the name of the object or the name of the tag, maybe this could help:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject terrain;
    public GameObject[] terrains;

    void Example()
    {
        // This returns the GameObject named Hand.
        terrain = GameObject.Find("Hand");

        // returns a list of the game objects with tags = 'terrain'
        terrains = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("terrain");

        //returns a single object with the tag terrain
        terrain = GameObject.FindWithTag("terrain");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` only find "activated" GameObjects, so it's not suitable for my situation. Thanks again!